# Returning filtered objects(list or queryset)

Tags: django, filtering, django-queryset, django-rest-framework

I need to filter some data in django rest framework filter. I have models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...
    connections = models.ManyToManyField(classB)
    ....


class B(models.Model):
   ...
   date_added=models.DateTimeField()
   ....
```

I need to return classA objects with filtered connections.

For example, **classA** objects has many connections with a different date_added field. I need to return **classA** objects with connections, but connections should be only from a specified date.

**classA** objects can contain different connections, but if it has a connection from a specified date, I need to return object from **classA**, containing connection which meets the condition, excluding connections which not meet that condition.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
A.objects.filter(connections__date_added=your_datetime)
```

Comment: That queryset will return all `classA` objects which have at least one connection meeting the specified condition. Then `classA` object can also has `connections` which not meet condition. I have to return all `classA` objects which have at least one `connection` meeting specified condition, but without `connections` which not meeting condition.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get a queryset of all class B objects for a given date.
Then do a reverse lookup for all connections related to that date. Then check if that manytomany set has any other connections that are != to the original given date, if not then add the class A objects to a list:

```
# queryset of all B objects for a specific date
b_queryset = B.objects.filter(date_added__date=my_datetime_date)

# Empty list to place all related A objects
a_list_initial = []

for x in b_queryset:
    # Add all related class A objects to a list
    [a_list_initial.append(y) for y in x.connections_set.all()]

# Empty list to finally place only desired A objects
desired_a_objects = []    
for z in a_list_initial:
    checker = all(item.date_added__date == my_datetime_date for item in z.connections.all())
    if checker == True:
        desired_a_objects.append(z)
```

It's not pretty but it will achieve what you are looking for :)
Sorry about all of the edits, this one was a bit of a mind bender.